# How to customize serialization of a PointF objectin c#

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have a project that serialize and deserialize a complex object. Its working fine, except for some PointF objects inside this object graph. Lets say i have this point: 
X:109.33 Y: 200

Each point will be serialized with its decimal separator, if needed (',' in Brazil), so it will be : 109,33 and 200. the problem is the point also use the ',' char to separate the two values, so the PointF serialization will be:

```
pointProp="109,33,200"
```

You can see the problem there. When I deserialize, i will get this point(X:109, Y: 33).

I think about two solutions, but i don't know how to implement neither of them. 
First would be to change the separator to a different char , like '|', so it would be serialized like: 
    pointProp="109,33|200"

the second solution would be to force serialization to use dot ('.') as a decimal separator. For that I would have force serialization to consider Us culture instead of Br culture, so it would be serialized like that:

```
pointProp="109.33,200"
```

Any tip on how to achieve any of that?

---

Sorry guys, Ignore the question, Just realized my problem is different. My Container object actually has a XMlIgnore on my PointF property and does its own serialization. In this case I just have to edit this method. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you share with us PointF class?

Comment: Its System.Drawing.PointF class. It has a X and Y properties, both float.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how do you serialize / deserialize these objects, but I'm sure that you should use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in this process to avoid such problems. Eventually change decimal separator:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```